# Python 2.7 built from source unable to import packages (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, python

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 VM running Python 2.7.6. 14.04 and Python 2.7 are requirements for what I'm working on, but I need to upgrade to a newer version of Python 2.7 because pip packages are failing to install due to lack of SNI support on 2.7.6.

I decided to download and build 2.7.18 from source. I then update the symlinks in `/usr/bin/python` to all point to the new 2.7.18 executable, which is at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.18/bin/python`.

The problem is that this new Python version is not finding a lot of site packages. For example, I am unable to `import apt_pkg`. I've tried adding `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which contains `apt_pkg.so`, to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and when I do `python -m site` I see it in `sys.path`, but it still fails to import `apt_pkg`. I've tried `apt remove python-apt` and `apt install python-apt` with no luck. The package was already there before building the new Python version.

I'm not sure what else to try. From what I've seen, replacing the system Python is generally a no-no, but that is what I would like to do. It seems like there is just some config I'm unaware of that needs to be updated for this new Python version.

Comment: Potentially several issues. You cannot simply replace symlinks to binaries and hope they all continue to work happily together. Some of the libraries (binaries as well as python packages) are often tied to specific versions, and you have to install the entire thing. Most likely, Python's make file has a `make install` and it probably allows you to specify where to install it without installing over your system installed version. But you will need to read the python build documentation to find out how.

Comment: better create `/usr/bin/python2.7.18` and run as `python2.7.18` (and `pip2.7.18`). If you need it to run script then you can use `shebang` in first line `#!/usr/bin/python2.7.18`, and set script executable `chmod +x script.py` and when you run `script.py` as normal problem (without `python`) then system will know that this script has to be run with `python2.7.18`. And when you test all your scripts then you can replace it.